# Postfix PCRE maps broken in RHEL8: "error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre"

Tags: rhel, postfix, pcre

My Postfix config worked flawlessly in ***RHEL 7*** and now all maps which rely on PCRE in RHEL are busted after migrating the config to ***RHEL 8***.

```
postfix/cleanup[xxxx]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
```

Is **PCRE** support deprecated in Postfix in RHEL 8?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ANSWER:

The error is a red-herring:

[Required Plugins weren't distributed in RHEL 8.0 - 8.1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1745321)

> "*In RHEL 8, the `postfix` package has been split into multiple
>   subpackages, each subpackage providing a plug-in for a specific
>   database. Previously, RPM packages containing the `postfix-pcre`,
>   `postfix-cdb`, and `postfix-sqlite` plug-ins were not distributed.
>   Consequently, databases with these plug-ins could not be used with
>   Postfix. This update adds RPM packages containing the PCRE, CDB, and
>   SQLite plug-ins to the AppStream repository. As a result, these
>   plug-ins can be used after the appropriate RPM package is installed.*"

### SOLUTION:

Problem to be fixed in future release:

> *Fixed In Version:    postfix-3.3.1-10.el8*

Hopefully save others migrating their Postfix installations to RHEL 8 some cycles resolving this issue-